# Query for all unique composites in a table that have one value, but not another

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am dealing with the following dataset, which is keyed on `Owner`/`Pet`, and I am trying to query for those Owners that **only** have a dog:

| Owner | Pet | Pet_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Dog | Fido |
| Jane | Cat | Oscar |
| Alex | Dog | Willy |
| Doug | Dog | Max |

Ideally, I would only get back the rows for `Alex` and `Doug`, however, the following SQL is just giving me back all the rows that have `Dog`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE Pet in ('Dog')
and Pet not in ('Cat')
```

| Owner | Pet | Pet_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Dog | Fido |
| Alex | Dog | Willy |
| Doug | Dog | Max |

My SQL kind of sucks, does the potential solution have anything to do with `DISTINCT`? I'm not sure how i should be phrasing my query to get the results i want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the full row, use `not exists`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE t.Pet in ('Dog') AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table t2 
                  WHERE t2.owner = t.owner AND
                        Pet IN ('Cat')
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what i was looking for. What is that `SELECT 1` pattern called if i wanted to learn more about how to apply it?

Comment: @EthanFox . . . The "pattern" is `EXISTS`.  That is an operator which you can learn more about in the Postgres documentation.  The `1` is arbitrary:  `EXISTS` only cares if a row is returned.  In Postgres, you can remove it and it will still work.